# Find convolution of x and y from their joint pdf

Tags: probability

I have been given the following joint pdf:
$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
    2(x+y)  &\text{for} \ 0\le x \le y \le 1 \\ 
    0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I've been asked to find pdf of Z = X+Y,
I attempted to solve this by first getting the marginal pdf for each variable so:
$$ f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} 2(x+y)dy = 2x+1$$
And with the same method $$f(y) = 2y+1$$
Now substitute back to the convolution formula:

$$ f(z) = \int_{}^{} f_Y(y)f_X(z-y)dy = \int_{}^{}(2y+1)(2(z-y)+1)dy$$
Here comes my question, I don't really know how to get the bound for the integral, from solution it says z can first take value from 0 to 1 then from 1 to 2.

Solution given from the textbook doesn't even break the joint pdf back the marginal pdf, but I could not understand that solution as most examples I found online gave 2 seperate pdf to begin with. If possible someone please educate me on both method. Thanks !

Comment: Substituting back into the "convolution formula" is incorrect since it means that effectively you are assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are _independent_ random variables (which they are not). What _is_ true is that $$f_Z(z) = f_{X+Y}(z) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate thanks for the reply, I understand this part now but I'm still struggling with getting the upper/lower bound for integral.

Comment: @ASPHO You wish to express $0\leqslant x\leqslant y\leqslant 1$ when $y=z-x$, which means that: $0\leqslant x\leqslant z-x\leqslant 1$ , so $$\big(0\leqslant z\lt 1~\cap~ 0\leqslant x\leqslant z/2\big)~\cup~\big(1\leqslant z\leqslant 2~\cap~ z-1\leqslant x\leqslant z/2 \big)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the point is that the joint distribution $f$ tells you everything you need to know about how $X$ and $Y$ are distributed, so finding the marginals is unnecessary because $f$ already tells you all the information you need. Moreover, it’s bad for more reasons: to use the convolution formula you need to use that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so you need to check this. And how would you work out the distribution if they aren’t? Another issue is what if I asked you to compute the distribution of soemthing more complicated such as $\sin (XY)$? Since you “know everything about how $X$ and $Y$ are distributed” in theory you should be able to do it, but computing the marginals doesn’t seem to help in anyway.

Here’s the better way to do it (and is probably the way the answer does it). Let $\tilde F(z)$ be the CDF of $X+Y$, that is, $\tilde F(z) = \operatorname{Pr}(X+Y\leq z).$ Then for each $z \in\mathbb R$ this probability is given by the integral over the region $U_z:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \text{ s.t. } x+y\leq z\}$ weighted by the density $f$. Hence, \begin{align*} 
\tilde F(z) = \iint_{U_z} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx
\end{align*} Moreover, $f$ is only non-zero in the region $\tilde U = \{ (x,y) \in U \text{ s.t. } 0\leq x \leq y \leq 1\}$ and $f=2(x+y)$ in this region, so we actually have $$\tilde F(z) = 2\iint_{U_z \cap \tilde U} (x+y) \, dy \, dx. \tag{$\ast$} $$ Now, what you need to do to complete the question is carefully check what the region $U_z \cap \tilde U$ is for every $z \in \mathbb R$ then compute the integral in $(\ast)$. To do this, I recommend you consider 4 cases separately:

1. $z\leq 0 $
2. $0<z\leq 1$
3. $1<z\leq 2$
4. $z>2$

Once you have done this you are practically done because you know the CDF, so then you compute $\tilde F’(z)$ which gives the PDF.

As an aside, if you did have to compute the PDF of something more complicated, say $\sin (XY)$ as above, then the argument is the exact same except you would take $U_z = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \text{ s.t. } \sin (xy) \leq z\}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks @JackT I could understand most of your response. Now I can tell that Case 1 & 4 are impossible and that case 2 & 3 are only possible when
$$0<x≤y≤\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2}<x≤y≤1$$
respectively. But now I struggle to express the bound in terms of z. For example for case 2, if y bounds from 0 to 1/2, then is x bound from 0 to z-y??

Comment: Let me just clarify that I wouldn’t say Case 1 and Case 4 are ‘impossible’. When $z\leq 0$ then $U_z \cap \tilde U$ is empty, so $\tilde F(z)=0$ in this case. When $z\geq 2$, $U_z\subset \tilde U$, so $\tilde F(z)=1$.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean with the inequalities you gave. Have you tried plotting the regions in Desmos/geogebra? The intersection (particularly in Case 3) is complicated. Go to desmos and write the command $0<x\leq y \{y<1\}$ to plot the region $\tilde U$. Then write a new command $x+y<z$ - when you click enter a slider will appear for $z$. Have a play and see what the intersection looks like